# How to validate this type of javascripts

Tags: javascript, validation

if input string is like

> 123karthik

```
alert ('correct format');
```

else if input string is like

> karthik123

```
alert('Invalid format')
```

Comment: The rules are not immediately obvious from the given examples. Are it the digits at end instead of in front? Please elaborate the rules in more detail like "Must not end with digits".

Comment: for a question u give -2 and for an invalid answer u guys give 6...if you dont understand, dont answer. its very hurting to get -2 for a question . I think you guys are friends with one another and putting + for your points and putting - for people like me. :((((

Comment: i will not ask any question from now... be happy

Comment: @Karthik: People are downvoting the question because you haven't given enough information to give a complete answer. Don't be discouraged! Take the advice that people like @BalusC have given and try to improve your question. People don't just vote for their friends. It's not that kind of site. StackOverflow is for people who genuinely want to help. There will always be some jerks, but I don't think you've encountered any in this case. Don't be put off even if you think I'm wrong.

Comment: @Karthik: BalusC's comment is not invalid. The question needs clarification. If you genuinely want help then you should consider adding more detail to the question. If you don't want help then that's your decision.

Comment: @Karthik: I also note that all three answers have one downvote each. Was that you? Do you really think that punishing the three people who have tried to help you will mean you get more help in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var regex = /[0-9]+[a-z]+/;
regex.test("karthik123") ? alert("yep") : alert("oops");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... It works for me :)
I don't know why people kept marking your question down. It was pretty simple to understand what you wanted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
function checkMe(){
var numChar=/^\d{3}\w+$/ 
if (document.myform.myinput.value.search(numChar)) 
alert("Please enter valid input inside form")
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myform">
<input type="text" name="myinput" size=15>
<input type="button" onClick="checkMe()" value="check">

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you want to use a [regular expression](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml). That's the most general (although sometimes also the most confusing) way to validate string data.

Comment: It is not "the most general" because it is not turing-complete.

Comment: Since when do people down vote just because they have a different opinion on an arguable subject?

Answer (score -1):

To check the input string you'd need something like this:
(because you seem new to javascript I'll only give you hints to help you learn)

```
var user_input = prompt("Please enter the input string"); 
if (user_input == "123karthik");
     alert('correct format');
else ...
```

I assume you can handle it on after the else!

NOTE: The code above is incomplete and is only for guidance.

Comment: I was just giving hints... No need to go and suck my reputation out of my brain.